# what is the difference between an unupvote and a downvote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I realized while checking out my profile, I was "unvoted". By definition, it is pretty clear that it is a negative vote, which I'm not contesting by the way. It is still a good answer that I am in positive standards with. I don't cry about downvotes. It's silly lol. But as we all know, we have the downvote feature. So, what is the difference between the two? Why don't they both fall under the umbrella of downvoting? Is unvoting a downvote from the same user who upvoted? Or was it a call back from a moderator after an accidental upvote? Or is it something else?

Seems weird to me that there is a distinction.

The one thing I did notice is that a downvote reduces your reputation by -2, meanwhile an unvote nulls the entire weight of a vote (-10).

Here's another kicker, when you hit the downvote arrow, how does it know that it is supposed to reduce it by -2 or -10? Is it because of who is the voting user?

I couldn't find anything like this in the regs.

Comment: You undo your vote. So you can click up-vote and you can click up-vote again. That is an un-up-vote.

Comment: You edited your post.  Whomever upvoted it before is no longer impressed with it.

Comment: So by clicking upvote twice,  you can unvote?

Comment: I realize there was a reason for the negative vote.  That's fine.  I was wondering about the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting an unupvote means that the user no longer wanted to give your post an extra vote, so they removed their original vote. This only removes one from your score, while a upvote-changed-to-a-downvote will remove two from your score.

> The one thing I did notice is that a downvote reduces your reputation by -2, meanwhile an unvote nulls the entire weight of a vote (-10).

A downvote and an upvote are two different votes. You can remove both of these votes after these are placed, which will reverse any reputation changes that were made as a result of these votes.

> Here's another kicker, when you hit the downvote arrow, how does it know that it is supposed to reduce it by -2 or -10?

An unupvote is different from giving a downvote, which would result in -12 reputation (-10 for the unupvote, -2 for the downvote).

You can remove an upvote by clicking the up arrow a second time.

Comment: Huh.  Cool.  Didn't know that

Comment: If often found the imbalance between up and down troubling. I have frequently seen Qs and As with a single downvote which I felt was undeserved. However, neither were they worthy of the whole +10 of an upvote. At those times I don't vote at all, but I wish I could do something.